# How bitwise operator works

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I dont get how the following codes work?

```
function odd($var){
   return ($var & 1);
}
echo odd(4); /* returns and print 0 */
echo odd(5); /* returns and print 1 */
```

this function returns true if argument is an odd number 
and returns false if argument is an even number. **How it works ?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: All this explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odd numbers in binary always have a least-significant bit (LSB) of 1. That is why your code

```
function odd($var){
   return ($var & 1);
}
```

returns true on odd numbers. Here are your examples from your question:

```
(decimal) 4 & 1 = (binary) 100 & 001 = (binary) 000 = (decimal) 0 = false
(decimal) 5 & 1 = (binary) 101 & 001 = (binary) 001 = (decimal) 1 = true
```

Another way to think of it is

```
    100 (decimal 4) - an even number 
AND 001 (decimal 1)  
  = 000 (decimal 0) - return false
```

and

```
    101 (decimal 5) - an odd number  
AND 001 (decimal 1)  
  = 001 (decimal 1) - return true
```

Answer (score 4):

bitwise comparison already says what it does: it compares the numbers bit by bit.

If we take 4 bits, the bit representation of 4 is: 0100. The bit representation of 5 is 0101. When we compare this with & (and), it returns the bits which are both set.

```
0100 & 0001 = 0000 (no bits are the same)
0101 & 0001 = 0001 (only Least Significant Bit (LSB) is 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is masking off all bits except 0.  `&` is the and operator.  And `1` is `000000000001` in binary.  So it works as it is named.